# Windows Mobile exception vs. if statement

Tags: c#, exception, if-statement

I'm rewriting a program in WM 6.0 on a MC67 and have noticed a lot of exception being thrown and catch as part of an ordinary flow. when i run the program i see about 5-10 exception per user click. i want to know if i should rewrite every exception i find, or at least most of them to an if-else statement. i searched for it on google and here and i know that if else statement cost less then exception, but it's not enough (at least from testing i've done) for it to be worth the trouble. are there any more reasons why i should rewrite the code?

if so then i'll need to convince my boss so I'll need details please

Comment: Can you provide more information about the exceptions you receive?

Comment: can you post stacktrace ?

Comment: well, the exception are logic flow, for example(and this is a common one) trying to get an integer from a string by doing parse, and when getting exception putting a default value. i can't give stack trace because there are too many

Comment: @LiranElisha, relying on exceptions for control flow is not really encouraged in C# (although it is in Python, for instance). I would suggest you refactor that code so it does not use exceptions that way. Using [TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead of [Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) would be a good starting point.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi there is no try parse on WM, but thank you. i still need to convince my boss though